# Does anyone know the manufacturer of bicycle parts with this logo?

Tags: stem, threadless

I would like to know the manufacturer of parts with the logo shown.
It's on a threadless stem, the stem is on a Specialized MTB from around 2001.
The logo is engraved into the metal (not a decal) on each side of the stem and on the bar clamp plate (see pics).
I haven't had any success after googling for it.
I will greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks and regards

[image: logo]

[image: stem side]

[image: stem bar plate]

Comment: I have seen something similar a few times.  It's never seemed to me to be a strong trademark, but just a humorous "art" bit.

Comment: That's not any logo for Specialized - could you post a larger picture of the whole stem ?   Is this engraved into the metal or a decal ?

Comment: Is there nothing else printed, etched or stamped anywhere on this part? In the second pic above, there appears to be something else printed on the "left" hand (top) side of the stem. What is that? Also, are there any model numbers stamped in the metal? Those may be harder to see.